# Radiobutton variable does not update

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I know a question similar to this has been asked and I have tried everything that was suggested to fix the problem but I can not solve this issue. I am making a document that when a radiobutton is pushed a second radiobutton appears, which has options that will vary based on response to the first radiobutton. The problem is that nothing happens after the first radiobutton is chosen, the variable is not set equal to the value, which it should if I understand correctly.. I have even gotten rid of my loops that created the buttons and added a secondary function in the command line in an effort to set the variable but no luck... I am beginning to think that this cannot be done using radiobuttons... Does anyone know if I am missing something that is not allowing the variable to be set?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, IntVar, Radiobutton

class pricingDoc:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Dyna-Vac Equipment Pricing GUI")

        models = ["DJ5.636", "DJ1225", "DJ2040", "DJ4020", "DJ4030", "DJ6520"]
        model_prices = [8139.00, 23770.00, 48050.00, 48040.00, 48030.00, 66050.0]
        reels = ["""3/8" x 150'""", """1/2" x 300'""", """1/2" x 500'""", """3/4" x 600'""",
                 """3/4" x 800'""", """1" x 600'""", """1" x 800'"""]
        reel_prices = [0.00, 0.00, 850.00, 0.00, 1050.00, 0.00, 850.00]

        self.label1 = Label(master, text="Jet Trailer Model")
        self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.label2 = Label(master, text="Price, in USD")
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=3)

        def showchoice(var1, updateint):
            var1.set(updateint)

        var1 = IntVar(master)

        row_counter = 2
        self.modelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=models[0], variable=var1, value=0, indicatoron=False,
                                           activebackground="green", width=12, command=lambda: showchoice(var1, 0))
        self.modelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1
        self.modelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=models[1], variable=var1, value=1, indicatoron=False,
                                         activebackground="green", width=12, command=lambda: showchoice(var1, 1))
        self.modelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1
        self.modelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=models[2], variable=var1, value=2, indicatoron=False,
                                         activebackground="green", width=12, command=lambda: showchoice(var1, 2))
        self.modelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1
        self.modelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=models[3], variable=var1, value=3, indicatoron=False,
                                         activebackground="green", width=12, command=lambda: showchoice(var1, 3))
        self.modelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1
        self.modelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=models[4], variable=var1, value=4, indicatoron=False,
                                         activebackground="green", width=12, command=lambda: showchoice(var1, 4))
        self.modelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1
        self.modelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=models[5], variable=var1, value=5, indicatoron=False,
                                         activebackground="green", width=12, command=lambda: showchoice(var1, 5))
        self.modelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)

        row_counter = 2

        for price in model_prices:
            self.label3 = Label(master, text=price)
            self.label3.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1

        self.label4 = Label(master, text="model {} is chosen".format(var1.get()))
        self.label4.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1

        self.label5 = Label(master, text="Reel Size Selection")
        self.label5.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
        row_counter += 1

        var2 = IntVar(master)

        if var1.get() == 0:
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[0], variable=var2, value=0, indicatoron=False,
                                                activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            row_counter += 1
            row_counter = 10
            self.label6 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[0])
            self.label6.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)

        elif 1 <= var1.get() <= 2:
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[1], variable=var2, value=1, indicatoron=False,
                                                activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            self.label6 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[1])
            self.label6.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[2], variable=var2, value=2, indicatoron=False,
                                            activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            self.label7 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[2])
            self.label7.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1

        elif 3 <= var1.get() <= 4:
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[3], variable=var2, value=3, indicatoron=False,
                                                activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            self.label6 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[3])
            self.label6.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[4], variable=var2, value=4, indicatoron=False,
                                            activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            self.label7 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[4])
            self.label7.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1

        elif var1.get() == 5:
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[5], variable=var2, value=5, indicatoron=False,
                                                activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            self.label6 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[5])
            self.label6.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1
            self.reelbutton = Radiobutton(master, text=reels[6], variable=var2, value=6, indicatoron=False,
                                            activebackground="green", width=12)
            self.reelbutton.grid(row=row_counter, column=1)
            self.label7 = Label(master, text=reel_prices[6])
            self.label7.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
            row_counter += 1

        row_counter += 1
        self.label8 = Label(master, text="Total unit price as built: {}".format(model_prices[var1.get()] +
                                                                                reel_prices[var2.get()]))
        self.label8.grid(row=row_counter, column=3)
        row_counter += 1





root = Tk()
my_gui = pricingDoc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. Can you illustrate the problem with just one or two Radiobuttons instead of five? Do you really need the labels if the problem is with a Radiobutton?

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you're calling `var1.get()` about a millisecond after creating the radiobutton. The user won't have had a chance to click on anything.

Comment: I second what Bryan said.  An MCVE for this might be only 10 lines.  After years of using tkinter, I still use simple minimal programs to experiment and debug problems.

Comment: thanks for the criticism, will definitely keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see and have tested in your code, it does not look to me like the elifs are encapsulated in a function that is called when a radio button is being clicked.

To test this theory, I threw a print(var1.get()) into the showchoice function and it prints out the new index with each click.  So to take that further I moved the label4 creation lines into that function as well and it updates the form properly.

So to me it just looks like the block of elifs need to be encapsulated into a function that is called (and thus updated) every time the radio buttons are clicked.

I Hope this helps or at least puts you on the right path.  I see no reason why radio buttons couldn't or shouldn't be used for what you're doing!

~Cheers!

Comment: ahhh, makes sense, I am going to give that a try, Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, Hal!  Best of luck!